# How can I retrieve my lost account?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I took a walk in the park and my old account fell out of my pocket. Can someone help me finding it or creating a new one? I do not want to miss my questions and answers.

Comment: Use a real email address etc so when you need a password reminder you will actually receive it.

Answer (score 3):

First up, try the account recovery page on the site you're trying to log back into - e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery. You can find this through the "forgot password?" link from the login page.

If you can't recall the email you used, you're *probably* out of luck, but you can try reaching out to the team via the "contact" link at the bottom of any page.